# Only repair and uninstall can be seen while relaunching bootstrapper application

Tags: wix, windows-installer, burn, wix3, wix3.11

I have an msi bundled with prerequisites using Wix bootstrapper. After installing the wix bootstrapper application, if i relaunch it again i could do only repair and uninstall. But i need to have modify option also.

In MSI i tried setting the property REINSTALLMODE as "vamus". after doing so, i was able to change / repair/ uninstall w.r.t. msi.
But bootstrapper application doesn't show modify option.

On relaunching the installed wix bootstrapper application, i am expecting to have below options.

> change, repair & uninstall.

Comment: Can any one tell if Modify is supported in Wix Bundle!

Answer (score 2):

A modify option makes only sense if you want to remove or add features included in an msi. May be a solution would be to set up your own bookkeeping on installed features and showing this list to the user in a custom bootstrapper application. 
Another way to handle this situation may be to show the msi installation dialog which should show a "modify" dialog option.

Comment: is there a way to show the msi installation dialog from bootstrapper when the application is already installed. this is my exact need.

Comment: In the bootstrapper configuration file you can set the attributes DisplayInternalUI="yes" EnableFeatureSelection="yes" InstallCondition="1" Visible="yes" of the <MsiPackage ...> tag to force the msi-installation to start and to show the UI.